# Symfony2 database configuration during deployment

Tags: php, symfony

hi i'm new to symfony2 web development. I have develop a sample symfony2 application with a database on my localhost. It is working fine on my localhost.

I have uploaded my project to web server, All the files are working on the web server other than the files connecting with databases. When I requested for the files that are connected with database I got these errors.

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   /home/pipeline/public_html/BusinessPipeline/BusinessPipeline/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php
>   on line 40
>
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=18547 in
>   /home/pipeline/public_html/BusinessPipeline/BusinessPipeline/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php
>   on line 40

I have setup the `parameters.yml` file as follows.

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver:    pdo_mysql
    database_host:      localhost
    database_name:      test_project
    database_user:      my_username
    database_password:  my_password
```

I didn't change anything rather than change the parameters.yml.

what can I do for this issue, do I need to do any configuration prior to deployment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there is a MySQL server running on localhost ?

Comment: And did you empty your application's cache after uploading it on the server ?

Comment: How did you deploy your code? Try a way [suggested in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

Comment: hi Saran, have you solve? how? thanks for share your experience

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL Server doc for specific problem about your error message:

[B.5.2.9 MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

Check the `wait_timeout` problem